# How to filter data shown using Forms Authentication?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I'm using Forms Authentication and SimpleMembership for login functionality in my ASP.NET MVC Application.

Now I'd like to filter what is shown to the user depending on which department the logged in user belongs to.

At first I thought about using User.Identity.Name, but since the data I wish to filter doesn't contain user name but rather a department id, I'd have to do extra joins on each filter (request).

This lead me to customizing the identity / principal by adding DepartmentId. Is that the correct way of doing it? Is it secure to store such information here (authorization cookie)? And should I add it to the identity or principal? I've seen examples of customizing both, so I'm a bit confusted. The examples I've seen was not about filtering but rather showing some extra information like an e-mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, that is the correct place, and as long as your encrypt the value in the cookie, you should be fine.  It is standard practice to use this sort of methodology, you customize the identity and then assign it to the httpcontext user in your authorize routine.

This lets you access it and tag it into any db request that you make so you can ensure that any data that is sent back is ok for that user to see.

It is one of the recommendations from oswap on security that every request for data is checked to ensure that it is valid for that user to see it.